# Filling a dataframe row using multiple nested loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm having a hard time understanding how I should structure this piece of code. There are multiple nested loops that iterate through lists of parameters, performing operations on a given  set of variables:

```
for s in s_parameters:
    for m in m_parameters:
        for f in f_parameters:
            variables = df[(df["s"]=s) & (df["m"]=m) & (df["f"]=f)]["variable"].to_numpy()
            variable_a = <operation involving variables>
            variable_b = <operation involving variables>
```

Where s_parameters, m_parameters, f_parameters are lists, and variables is a list composed from a pre-existing dataframe. The result I'm trying to produce should look like this:

```
| s  | m  | f1 variable_a | f1 variable_b | f2 variable_a | f2 variable_b |
|----|----|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
| s1 | m1 | v1            | v2            | v3            | v4            |
| s1 | m2 | v5            | v6            | v7            | v8            |
| s2 | m1 | v9            | v10           | v11           | v12           |
| s2 | m2 | v13           | v14           | v15           | v16           |
```

...

where:

```
s_parameters = [s1, s2]
m_parameters = [m1, m2]
f_parameters = [f1, f2]
```

How would I go about writing values to a dataframe with the shape of the above example?

Comment: So what does the original dataframe, df, look like?

Answer (score 1):

As I suppose, for each combination of *s*, *m* and *f* source
parameters, you should have only 2 values of the fourth variable,
e.g. *'a'* and *'b'*. They should be **just the same** for all combinations
of *s*, *m* and *f* as otherwise you would get columns with different
names and the resulting table would contain much more columns
than your expected result.

To avoid nested loops while creating your result, proceed as follows:

1. Start from `import itertools`.
2. Create lists of possible values for *s*, *m*, *f* and also *variable*:

   ```
   s_parameters = ['s1', 's2']
   m_parameters = ['m1', 'm2']
   f_parameters = ['f1', 'f2']
   v_parameters = ['a', 'b']
   ```
3. Create the source DataFrame, containing for now only 4 above columns:

   ```
   df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(s_parameters, m_parameters, f_parameters, v_parameters),
       columns=['s', 'm', 'f', 'variable'])
   ```
4. Now it is time to set values for each combination of your source
   parameters - *n* column.
   As I don't know how you want to compute this column, I put the
   following "surrogate" code:

   ```
   df = df.assign(n=list(map(lambda x: 'v' + str(x), range(1, df.index.size + 1))))
   ```

   Print *df* to see the result.
5. As you want column names as a **single level**, join *f*
   and *variable* columns in *variable* and drop *f* column:

   ```
   df.variable = df.f + ' variable_' + df.variable
   df.drop(columns='f', inplace=True)
   ```

   Print *df* again to see the result.
6. And to get the final result, run:

   ```
   result = df.pivot(index=['s', 'm'], columns=['variable'], values='n')
   result.columns.name = None
   ```

The result is:

```
      f1 variable_a f1 variable_b f2 variable_a f2 variable_b
s  m                                                         
s1 m1            v1            v2            v3            v4
   m2            v5            v6            v7            v8
s2 m1            v9           v10           v11           v12
   m2           v13           v14           v15
```

## Edit

A more realistic code to generate *n* column, using explicitely
all 4 source parameters, can be to define a function generating
an output value from all parameters from the current row:

```
def vv(row):
    return row.s + '_' + row.m + '_' + row.f + '_' + row.variable
```

apply it to each row of *df* and save the result in a new column
(instead of *df.assign* in the above code):

```
df['n'] = df.apply(vv, axis=1)
```

Of course, this time results for each combination of source parameters
is their values separated with an underscore.